# Find a reduce math function with increase param value

Tags: functions

I have a d value which is a range from $0\to5$. I want to build a math function with $d$ param so that return a value from $0$ to $1$. if $d$ increase, function decrease faster. Example $f (d = 0) = 1, f (d = 1) = 0.1, f (d = 2) = 0.01$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, Exponential function may satisfy your needs:

```
Plot[Exp[-x],{x,0,5}]
```

[image]